# C# LinkedList addAfter to reverse

Tags: c#

I'm studying for interviews, and trying to reverse a linked list in C#. I've done it manually with my own node class, and I've done it using a copylist. Now I'm trying to do it by altering the original list.

I created a static method:

```
    public static void reorderList(LinkedList<String> list)
    {
        LinkedListNode<String> a;
        LinkedListNode<String> lastNode;

        lastNode = list.Last;
        list.RemoveLast();
        list.AddFirst(lastNode);
        lastNode = list.First;

        Console.WriteLine(list.Find(lastNode.Value));            
        for (int i=1;i<=list.Count;i++)
        {
            a = list.Last;
            list.RemoveLast();
            list.AddAfter(lastNode,a);
            lastNode = a;
        }
    }
```

The idea was to take the last node, place it as the first, then take each subsequent last node and place it after the previously moved node. However I receive an error "'The LinkedList node does not belong to current LinkedList." and I can't figure out why lastNode might not belong to the list (as I literally assigned it from the list.First)

Comment: _"I can't figure out why lastNode might not belong to the list"_ -- did you try to debug the problem? One of the first things I'd look at, were I the person debugging this, would be to monitor the state of the list as the method proceeds, watching to see if and when the `lastNode` object no longer is a member of the list. Pay close attention to the number of iterations of your `for` loop, as it compares to the number of nodes you actually should be moving by the time you get to that `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is iterating too many times. The total number of moves should be the number of nodes minus 1.  You are performing the first move prior to entering the loop, so you for loop should only iterate 2 less than the count.
Consider a simple 3 node list:

```
1,2,3
```

Before entering the loop you move 3 to the first position:

```
3,1,2
```

First iteration of for loop, i=1, moves 2 after 3:

```
3,2,1
```

You should stop here!
Second iteration i=2, moves 1 after 2, no change:

```
3,2,1
```

Third iteration i=3, lastNode is now 1, but it's going to remove last node (also 1) and then try to add it after the lastNode which is no longer in the list:

```
3,2 (1 is removed)
```